# Display parent link in children ul list

Tags: javascript

I made menu - wordpress pages (parent / children ) working as tabs.. so when I click on parent ul li.page_item_has_children I get > ul.children opened, and that works fine.

Since I have parent page that is not accesaible I need sollution to have that link displayed into children menu

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item_has_children"> <a>Parent 1</a>
         <ul class="children">
              <!- I need Parent 1 to be displayed as link here ->
              <li> Children 1 </li>
              <li> Children 2 </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item_has_children"> <a>Parent 2</a>
</ul>
```

Hope anyone help :)
Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by `Since I have parent page that is not accesaible I need sollution to have that link displayed into children menu`? Could you provide further explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, here you can see that menu - zzpstart.nl
If you open 'menu' you'll find tabs menu that is made of wordpress pages listed.
Links on the left are parents and if you click on those links you'll get children ul displayed on the right side. 
But then I dont have link to parent page because I removed action from that link in order to open children menu working like tabs.
I need sollution to get that parent link dispayed in children ul so you can open parent page too. is this more precise? 

THX!

Comment: Ohh, I think I'm starting to understand the problem you have. I'm not sure though of what do you want to do to overcome it. Do you want the first item of the `li` children to be the same of the parent `li` so that you can access the parent URL? In that case, why not build the HTML like that?

Comment: Yes :) but cant make it with html because menu is pulling links dinamicaly from wp pages.. so it list all pages I have on website in parent / children structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the parent anchor tag inside its children by executing:

```
$(function() {
    $('.page_item_has_children').each(function() {
        var $parent = $(this);
        var $anchor = $parent.children('a');
        var href = $anchor.attr('href');
        var text = $anchor.text().trim();

        $parent.find('.children').prepend('<li><a href="' + href + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: hey @mgarcia thank you very much!
This working only that link is looking like this <a href="undefined">Bankzaken</a>
Obviously doesnt get ancor

Comment: Is it possible that your parent element does not have an `href` attribute defined?

Comment: not :( because that page exist I just removed click on parent in menu.. but if you inspect that parent link you'll see that it has a href. or if you open any page from children menu and see breadcrumbs you'll find link to that page too. 
So, yes, definitelly has a href just doesn't take it with script.

Comment: I have edited my answer. There was indeed an error when getting the `href` attribute.